# In memory, what is happening when I re-assign a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, memory

Lately I've been working with larger and larger datasets, that I'm currently handling with pandas DataFrames.  I want to understand whats going in memory management a bit better.  I've heard it said that pandas doesn't release memory the same way numpy does, which makes numpy better for handling larger data sets, but I've not yet found an explanation about whats going under the hood.  For example, If I had the following code snippet:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame('file2.csv')
for i in range(some_large_number):
    df1 = df1.add(df2)
```

Is the add method returns a new dataframe.  Does that mean in each iteration I'm abandoning a chunk of memory that wont be freed until df1 has gone out of scope?  I'd love an answer on this question in particular, and if anyone has recommendations for useful resources in this area, please let me know.

`